# Updating values from specific key in list of dictionaries based on a separate list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with identical keys. Some keys have integer values, a few have string values, and one key has a set value for the first dictionary and *None* for all the remaining dictionaries.

Example of the first dictionary in the list of dictionaries is found here:

```
dicts = [{'foul': 1, 'lineup': set(['Player 1', 'Player 2']), 'Date': '11/12/2016}...
```

Example of the second and third dictionary in the list of dictionaries:

```
...{'foul': 6, 'lineup': None, 'Date': '11/19/2016}, {'foul': 12, 'lineup': None, 'Date': '11/22/2016}]
```

Here is an example list of values I want to use to update these three dictionaries:

```
listofvals = [set('Player 4', 'Player 2'), set('Player 2', 'Player 3'), set('Player 6', 'Player 1')]
```

Note that regardless of what the value is in the first dictionary, I want to update all dictionaries in the list of dicts in the order of the list above.

Such that the list of dictionaries returned is as follows:

```
desired_product = 
[{'foul': 1, 'lineup': set(['Player 4', 'Player 2']), 'Day': '11/12/2016},
{'foul': 6, 'lineup': set(['Player 2', 'Player 3']), 'Day': '11/19/2016}, 
{'foul': 12, 'lineup': set(['Player 6', 'Player 1']), 'Day': '11/22/2016}]
```

I have tried variations on the following:

```
for index, d in enumerate(dicts):
    stnt.update((k, listofvals[idx]) for k, v in stnt.iteritems() if v == None or type(v) == 'set')
```

Another thing I've tried:

```
for index, d in enumerate(dicts):
    for key, val in d.interitems():
        setattr(d["lineup"], key, listofvals[idx])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for index,d in enumerate(dicts):
    d["lineup"] = listofvals[index]
```

Comment: First one gives following error: TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing

Comment: Second one only returns a single player out of the list of vals.

Comment: Any more suggestions here?

Comment: can you print the type() listval to confirm that it is list of sets

Comment: Also can you validate that each element in dicts is a dictionary

Comment: Dicts: [<type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>]

Comment: Listofvals is a <type 'set'>, with each value in the set a <type 'str'>

Comment: Listofvals should be a list of sets instead a set. I think this is your issue